# How can I use Ansible to run playbooks into GCP GCE VMs whilst using the Control Node's GCP account and IAM permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, ansible, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to SSH into a Compute Engine VM via Ansible, so that I'm able to interact with a GKE Private Cluster. This VM is in an Ansible Dynamic Inventory, and when I say I want to SSH into it, I mean that I want to be able to run an ansible playbook into it, and not explicitly SSH from another machine other than the Control Node.

I am able to SSH into that VM, but, apparently, when I do so, I'm authenticated on the VM with the VM's attached Service Account, and I'd like to use my own GCP account's credentials, [which I am able to do on the Ansible Control Node machine by using `gcloud compute ssh`, since I'm authenticated with the gcloud CLI on that machine.]*
Is there any way that I could use those credentials to SSH into that VM with Ansible?

I am aware that I could just give the VM Service Account the needed IAM roles or use another Service Account, by generating a Service Account Key, copying it to the VM and using the gcloud CLI inside the VM to authenticate with that key, but I'm trying to avoid both of these alternatives for security reasons. Other alternatives are welcome.

*Edit: Apparently, when I SSH via `gcloud auth ssh`, I am **not** authenticated as myself. Running `gcloud auth list` on the VM showed me that the only credentials available inside the VM are the VM's service account.

Edit 2: Included mention to the Dynamic inventory and provided more detailed explanation.

Comment: When you SSH into a VM instance, the credentials are derived from the attached service account to the VM unless configured otherwise. Using ADC (Application Default Credentials), the CLI running on the VM searches for credentials. By default only the metadata service provides credentials. If you want different credentials, you can configure the CLI `gcloud` with your user or service account. Think of it as two sets of credentials: 1) The SSH user that logs into the OS and 2) The IAM identity that has been assigned to the virtual machine for interaction with other Google Cloud resources.

Answer (score 0):

1- Install the ansible-galaxy role google-auth on the Ansible Control Node machine.
2 - Create an Ansible playbook that uses the gcp_compute_auth plugin to authenticate with GCP and then uses the ssh module to SSH into the Compute Engine VM
3 - Please check the code that i used in my playbook to achieve this

```
- name: SSH into Compute Engine VM with GCP credentials
  hosts: compute_engine_vm
  tasks:
  - name: Authenticate with GCP
    google.auth.gcp_compute_auth:
      scopes:
      - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    register: auth_result

  - name: SSH into Compute Engine VM
    ssh:
      user: "your-username"
      host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      port: 22
      become: true
    delegate_to: localhost
    environment:
      ACCESS_TOKEN: "{{ auth_result.access_token }}"
```

Ansible Control Node machine and stores the resulting access token in the access_token variable. The ssh module then uses this access token to SSH into the Compute Engine VM. I hope this can fullfill your need as per your security requirements

Comment: It seems like this makes sense, but I'm using a dynamic inventory and I mean to run the playbook in the controlled node I'm trying to SSH into (I believe that I haven't explained this adequately in my question).

I believe this wouldn't work, since I'd have to SSH into another node in the inventory so that I could use that node to SSH into the targeted node.